How to reverse engineer dashboard in ibm cognos?
I have a dashboard created in IBM Cognos. I want to know from where data is coming to this dashboard and the logic behind those queries. Our organization has a data warehouse and data engineers have created some measures by using that warehouse. These measures and data from some tables are used to create this dashboard.
I have permission to edit the dashboard but don't know how to do reverse engineering to get those queries and logic.

You say Cognos and dashboard.  That's vague.  I assume this is IBM Cognos Analytics, but what version.  Also, considerably more detail about your problem is needed.  For example, does the dashboard use a package, a data module, a spreadsheet,...?

Apology if I am using the wrong words but that is what my organization is using or maybe I misunderstood it somewhere. I am using version 12.0.1 for the IBM Cognos Analytics. Answering your last comment, the dashboard uses a package.

You'll need to get your IBM Cognos Analytics Administrator (probably one of those "data engineers" you mentioned) to perform most of these tasks:
To get the logic used:

Identify and locate the source object (package, data module, etc.) that the dashboard is using.
If it is a package

locate the Cognos model that was used to publish the package.
Open the model in Framework Manager (FM).
Inspect the FM model.



To get the actual queries that the dashboard is using:

In Cognos Configuration, enable auditing to a database.
In Cognos Administration, change "Audit logging level for query service" to Request

You may also need to enable these settings:

Audit the native query for report service
Audit the native query for batch report service





Once that is done, open the dashboard and click each feature you want to inspect.  Then go run an audit report to see the hundreds of queries that clicking around the dashboard just produced.
